# Disabling plugin when command is met

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm working on a Bukkit plugin, and I want to disable the plugin, if the config `file = false`...

config:

```
DeathmessagesListenerDisable: false
```

Main file:

```
public static void start() {
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DeathmessagesListener(), r.getUC());
    //Set deathmessages
    if (r.getCnfg().getBoolean("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable") == false) {
        //stuff
        return;
    } //rest off code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your doing with your start() method or when/how its getting called but the general way of doing this would to put something like this in your `onEnable()`

```
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    if (r.getCnfg().getBoolean("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable") == false) {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
        return;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this corresponds with what OP instructs as the expected behaviour.

Comment: So it would be like:
`public static void start() {
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DeathmessagesListener(), r.getUC());
    //Set deathmessages
    if (r.getCnfg().getBoolean("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable") == false) {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(<PLUGIN INSTANCE>);
        return;
    } //rest off code`

Comment: @EsliStavenga could you post your whole main class. It's hard for me to know what your doing with a single generic method.

Comment: Ill give u the link to github :P... thats the most up-to-date version

Comment: https://github.com/Bammerbom/UltimateCore/blob/master/src/main/java/bammerbom/ultimatecore/bukkit/UltimateCore.java

Comment: @EsliStavenga where is the method from your question?

Comment: @EsliStavenga the code you put in your question? Is it on github?

Comment: or should Bukkit.getPluginManager... be in the onenable?

Comment: only my part,
`if (r.getCnfg().getBoolean("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable") == false) {
            Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(DeathmessagesListener);
        } is not on there`

Comment: @EsliStavenga updated my answer. Should be easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable your plugin, you can call

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(plugin);
```

Where `plugin` is your plugin's instance. So, if this was in your main class, you would use

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
```

So all you have to do is check if the config value is false in your `onEnable()` method, and disable the plugin if it is

```
public class MyMainClass extends JavaPlugin{

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        //check if the config contains the value before checking if it's false
        //remove just the below contains() check to disable the plugin if
        //the config doesn't contain a value for "Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable" 
        if(this.getConfig().contains("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable")){

            //this could be replaced with any other check(s) that should be
            //done to see if the plugin should be disabled or not
            if(!this.getConfig().getBoolean("Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable")){
                //disable the plugin
                Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
                return;
            }
        }
        //normal onEnable() stuff
    }

    //your code
}
```

Also, just from a UX prespective, I would recommend changing the name of `Chat.DeathmessagesListenerDisable` to `Chat.DeathmessagesListenerEnabled`, because some may think they have to set the value to true to disable the plugin.